# How to set up hibernation with Secure Boot enabled

Tags: boot, partitioning, uefi, hibernate, cryptswap

Working on a new Ubuntu install. On my ASUS laptop, Secure Boot is enabled (and likely may need to stay that way due to the pestilence of Windows 11). Reading from `journalctl -b` has some mention of kernel lockdown mode, and further along, indications of my traditional resume from swap with GRUB method not allowed to be used because of kernel lockdown mode. So...

How can one properly set up an encrypted swap when making a brand new install of Ubuntu 23.10 (and newer) to allow not only for an encrypted swap that satisfies kernel lockdown mode, but also allows for hibernation, without requiring a password to unlock the disk? Suppose the target system is an x86_64-efi platform with 16 GB of RAM and 512 GB of NVMe storage. Can this all be done in the pre-install environment as well?